# INSERT ... SELECT Syntax doesn't insert all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query it returns 6,338 total rows.

```
  SELECT updated.playerId
  FROM updated WHERE updated.updated = 0;
```

However, when I run this query it only inserts 2,771 total rows, when it should insert all 6,338.

```
  INSERT IGNORE INTO playerold (playerID)
  SELECT updated.playerId
  FROM updated WHERE updated.updated = 0;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `IGNORE`

Comment: I get this error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'playerID'. But there is no playerID that equals 0 in either table.

Comment: @user1626410, Because you're trying to add already been added row.

Comment: You have unique key constraint in your playerold table.

Comment: Well all those rows that generate an error won't be inserted when you use the `IGNORE` keyword.

Comment: And how many rows do you get if you do `select u.playerId from updated u where u.updated = 0 and exists (select null from playerold where playerID = u.playerID)` ? Maybe 6638 - 2771  => 3867 ?

Comment: [Found interesting link on SE for INSERT IGNORE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7853634/2679536)

Comment: And what do you really want : be able to have multiple times the same playerId in oldPlayer table, or not ? If yes, you'll have to change this table's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Remove the unique constraint available in playerold table if you want all the records and use the below query:

```
 INSERT INTO playerold (playerID)
 SELECT updated.playerId
 FROM updated WHERE updated.updated = 0;
```

Or,

2  Try:

```
 INSERT INTO playerold (playerID) VALUES (SELECT updated.playerId
 FROM updated WHERE updated.updated = 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE playerID=playerID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error you need to remove the word IGNORE your sql statement.
I think you have a different constraint in another table.
Check table constraints.

You can try `CREATE TABLE playerold SELECT playerID FROM updated WHERE updated.updated = 0;`